# Fibonacci sequence in solving an equation

Tags: recursion, fibonacci

Im trying to figure out an equation. This is f(n)=f(n-1) + 3n^2 - n. I also have the values to use as f(1), f(2), f(3). How would i go about solving this??

Answer (score 1):

You would usually use recursion but, whether you do that *or* an iterative solution, you're missing (or simply haven't shown us) a vital bit of information, the terminating condition such as `f(1) = 1` (for example).

With that extra piece of information, you could code up a recursive solution relatively easily, such as the following pseudo-code:

```
define f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    return f(n-1) + (3 * n * n) - n
```

---

As an aside, that's not *actually* Fibonacci, which is the *specific* `1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, ...` sequence.

It can be said to be Fibonacci-like but it's actually more efficient to do this one recursively since it only involves *one* self-referential call per level whereas Fibonacci needs two:

```
define f(n):
    if n <= 2:
        return 1
    return f(n-2) + f(n-1)
```

---

And if you're one of those paranoid types who doesn't like recursion (and I'll admit freely it *can* have its problems in the real world of limited stack depths), you could opt for the iterative version.

```
define f(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    parent = 1
    for num = 2 to n inclusive:
        result = parent + (3 * num * num) - num
        parent = result
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you ask this question on a programming site such as Stack Overflow, you can expect to get code as an answer.

On the other hand, if you are looking for a closed formula for `f(n)`, then you should direct your question to a specialised StackExchange site such as [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Note: what you are looking for is called the repertoire method. It can be used to solve your problem (the closed formula is very simple).